# Populate a Word Template with Dynamic Data From a HTML Form on a Sharepoint Page

Tags: list, javascript, word-automation

I have a SharePoint site. What I want to do is:
1) Upload a Proposal Template and create an HTML form that allows our sales guys to enter customer details
2) Allow the sales guy to select some options on the form ( that using Javascript/Jquery will do some calculations, to create price/scope

for example

```
int TotalPrice
createTotalPrice(int Rooms, int Margin)
{
  TotalPrice = ((Rooms * 500)/ (margin/100))
}
```

3) Then populate the template document with these values
4) Allow the sales person to download the new document
5) Email the Sales Manager with a copy of the proposal.

To be clear, this will be dynamic data that will not exist in an existing database or list. So the method of mapping to a list initially will not work. I am not opposed to having the form populate the list and the list populate the template document although this would add additional steps.

Any advice/ideas are appreciated.

-Phil

Answer (score 0):

Do do exactly what you require, you will need to modify the form for the list by placing the entire java-script for your 'calculator' into it, and then saving that data to a list.  Then, you would use the Insert > Quick Parts > Document Properties option in Word to display that information from the SharePoint list.  You will need a content type to do this, of course.
To modify the form with your custom javascript, you will need a form editor such as InfoPath, Nintex Forms or if you are comfortable enough, editing the editform.aspx page directly for that library.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Unfortunately, our IT group will give us zero access to add any plugins, so everything I do will have to be with default SharePoint parts, and embedded code. Do you know if the editform.aspx is accessible via the web browser or do I need to be connected to the Sharepoint machine?

Comment: If you can open up the library in Windows explorer view, and see the hidden 'forms' folder (turn on 'show hidden files' in windows explorer), you should be able to modify the editform.aspx page without issue.  This completely depends on your permission level you have on that particular document library.

Comment: @Phil if this answer helped you, could you please mark it as the answer?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you use Microsoft Forms or something similar?

I would get around this situation this way --

1. Make a Word template
2. Set up a Microsoft Form for your people to fill in
3. Use Encodian (free for up to 50 entries per month, I think?) on Power Automate to map Microsoft Forms to Word. More robust than Word Premium connector.
4. Follow an Encodian how-to to do it all. They have very thorough step-by-step guides on their website
5. You can attach things and email things through Power Automate
6. You can add to your Sharepoint list using Power Automate for whatever answers are filled in on the Microsoft Form

The only clunky bit in this scenario is Microsoft Forms, as it can't, for whatever reason, do calculations. I have used CognitoForms to get around this for order forms before, with great results (also free for basics).